# ExtJs slider bar chart

Tags: extjs, extjs-chart

I am trying to find Slider bar chart functionality in ExtJs like we have Google finance chart given in the link below:

http://www.google.com/ig/directory?type=gadgets&url=www.google.com/ig/modules/finance_chart.xml

for example: We have scrollable long chart and as we scroll or slide the part of the chart, that is shown as chart in real big view.

Please let me know if we have this chart in ExtJs. If not, then please let me know if we have this chart in fusion charts or any third party library that we can integrate that in ExtJS.

Comment: I might write this one for ext :)